# Normalizing Order / Sequence

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, database-normalization

I cannot find a solution on this anywhere in google or otherwise. Maybe my terminology is wrong.

I am trying to figure out how to normalize the sequencing in a table like this in `MySQL`:

```
| id | job   | action         | sequence |
| :- | :---- | :------------- | :------- |
| 1  | build | Procure Wood   | 1        |
| 2  | build | Grab Hammer    | 2        |
| 3  | build | Hammer         | 3        |
| 4  | drill | Get Screw      | 1        |
| 5  | drill | Charge Drill   | 2        |
| 6  | drill | Start Drilling | 3        |
```

> Please ignore the fact that both the `job` and `action` columns are not normalized, that is not the part of the question - just part of the example.

For instance, what if I want to now insert a new action of `Get Nails` for the `build` job. This would go after `Grab Hammer` but before `Hammer`. If it were plainly inserted (then `ORDER BY job, sequence`), you would get the following:

```
| id | job   | action         | sequence     |
| :- | :---- | :------------- | :----------- |
| 1  | build | Procure Wood   | 1            |
| 2  | build | Grab Hammer    | 2            |
| 7  | build | Get Nails      | 3            |
| 3  | build | Hammer         | 3 <- problem |
| 4  | drill | Get Screw      | 1            |
| 5  | drill | Charge Drill   | 2            |
| 6  | drill | Start Drilling | 3            |
```

Or, if I want to re-arrange the `Charge Drill` and `Get Screw` actions in the `drill` job, I would set the sequence of `Charge Drill` to equal the sequence of `Get Screw`. But then, the other two actions would be not sequenced properly. The options I see are:

1. A way to "cascade" the sequencing through the later rows. I can't think of a pure SQL method for this and it might need to be handled through a script running a `transaction` on the table.
2. Instead of `sequence`, the column is `behind`. In this column goes the `id` of whichever row is ahead of it. But I have no idea how SQL would sort that (i.e. in `ORDER BY`), and really the same problem as above would still exist (what if two rows point to the same `id`).

I am looking for a more standard pure-SQL method, if possible.

Comment: Job and action appear to be normalised

Comment: @philipxy I'm normally the first to complain, but this one seems clear enough to me

Comment: @Strawberry I expect you are guessing from a few words being used like "sequence" & the example data. This is so poorly written I'm not interested in guessing.

Comment: Strange. I don't feel like I'm guessing

Comment: @Strawberry I expect that you are reporting the impression that you don't have to guess very hard. That doesn't mean you're not guessing or that the text makes sense.

Comment: Well in that sense, that's true of all my interactions on here.

Comment: Instead of the sequence being 1, 2, 3, etc., make the sequence 10000, 20000, 30000, etc.  That way, you have plenty of room for inserts.  You can also renumber your sequence on occasion to preserve the large gaps.

Comment: Or use a `FLOAT` for the sequence, then you can insert a new value in between any two existing values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider doing this as a two step process, so, first add (insert) the new action to the table, with a null sequence number. Then 'move' it to the correct position (update), so set its id to 3, and set the ids of all related actions (greater than or equal to 3) to sequence + 1...

```
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table  (
      `id` Serial primary key,
      `job` varchar(12),
      `action` VARCHAR(20),
      `sequence` int);

    INSERT INTO my_table 
      (`id`, `job`, `action`, `sequence`)
    VALUES
      ('1', 'build', 'Procure Wood',1),
      ('2', 'build', 'Grab Hammer',2),
      ('3', 'build', 'Hammer',3),
      ('4', 'drill', 'Get Screw',1),
      ('5', 'drill', 'Charge Drill',2),
      ('6', 'drill', 'Start Drilling',3);

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY job,sequence; 
+----+-------+----------------+----------+
| id | job   | action         | sequence |
+----+-------+----------------+----------+
|  1 | build | Procure Wood   |        1 |
|  2 | build | Grab Hammer    |        2 |
|  3 | build | Hammer         |        3 |
|  4 | drill | Get Screw      |        1 |
|  5 | drill | Charge Drill   |        2 |
|  6 | drill | Start Drilling |        3 |
+----+-------+----------------+----------+

      insert into my_table
      (job,action,sequence) values 
      ('build','grab nails',null);

      UPDATE my_table x 
        JOIN 
           ( SELECT a.id
                  , CASE WHEN a.sequence IS NULL THEN 3 
                         WHEN a.sequence >=3 THEN a.sequence +1 ELSE a.sequence 
                     END new_seq     
               FROM my_table a
               JOIN my_table b
                 ON b.job = a.job
              WHERE b.id = LAST_INSERT_ID()
           ) y 
          ON y.id = x.id 
         SET x.sequence = y.new_seq; 

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY job,sequence;
+----+-------+----------------+----------+
| id | job   | action         | sequence |
+----+-------+----------------+----------+
|  1 | build | Procure Wood   |        1 |
|  2 | build | Grab Hammer    |        2 |
|  7 | build | grab nails     |        3 |
|  3 | build | Hammer         |        4 |
|  4 | drill | Get Screw      |        1 |
|  5 | drill | Charge Drill   |        2 |
|  6 | drill | Start Drilling |        3 |
+----+-------+----------------+----------+
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mBAYoVB69UNk76GcU1QCrb/1

Comment: @4lackof - As you can see, re-sequencing items in a database table is a clumsy operation.

Answer (score 0):

Normalization is about removing redundancy and logical errors from a database. Redundancy often leads to logical errors, though in most cases these errors are result of no-design approach, or due to jumping directly into physical design.

Here is an example of one possible logical design.

```
-- Job named JOB_NAME exists
--
job {JOB_NAME}
 PK {JOB_NAME}


-- Action named ACTION_NAME exists.
--
action {ACTION_NAME}
    PK {ACTION_NAME}


-- Job JOB_NAME involves action ACTION_NAME.
--
job_action {JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME}
        PK {JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME}
       FK1 {JOB_NAME}    REFERENCES job    {JOB_NAME}
       FK2 {ACTION_NAME} REFERENCES action {ACTION_NAME}


-- Action ACTION_NAME has associated step number STEP_NO in job JOB_NAME.
--
job_step {JOB_NAME, STEP_NO, ACTION_NAME}
      PK {JOB_NAME, STEP_NO}

FK1 {JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME} REFERENCES job_action {JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME}
```

At this point you can start thinking about physical design: sizes of columns indexes, etc., and decide to add numerical `IDs` to use for `PKs`. Depending on the DB size, RDBMS and hardware used, you may decide to leave it as is. I am *deliberately* avoiding adding `IDs` at this point.

---

The example is PostgreSQL (have it installed) -- should be easy to adjust for MySQL. For MySQL use `varchar(25)` instead of `TEXT` and the example should work fine (not tested).

```sql
CREATE TABLE job (
    JOB_NAME TEXT NOT NULL

  , CONSTRAINT pk_job PRIMARY KEY (JOB_NAME)
);


CREATE TABLE action_ (
    ACTION_NAME TEXT NOT NULL

  , CONSTRAINT pk_action PRIMARY KEY (ACTION_NAME)
);


CREATE TABLE job_action (
    JOB_NAME    TEXT NOT NULL
  , ACTION_NAME TEXT NOT NULL

, CONSTRAINT pk_job_action PRIMARY KEY (JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME)

, CONSTRAINT fk1_job_action
    FOREIGN KEY (JOB_NAME) REFERENCES
            job (JOB_NAME)

, CONSTRAINT fk2_job_action
    FOREIGN KEY (ACTION_NAME) REFERENCES
        action_ (ACTION_NAME)
);


CREATE TABLE job_step (
      JOB_NAME    TEXT   NOT NULL
    , ACTION_NAME TEXT   NOT NULL
    , STEP_NO     BIGINT NOT NULL

, CONSTRAINT pk_job_step PRIMARY KEY (JOB_NAME, STEP_NO)

, CONSTRAINT fk1_job_step
    FOREIGN KEY (JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME) REFERENCES
     job_action (JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME)
);
```

Insert some test data; note that step numbers are not sequential, leaving spaces for future mid-steps.

```sql
INSERT INTO job (JOB_NAME)
VALUES
    ('build')
  , ('drill')
;

INSERT INTO action_ (ACTION_NAME)
VALUES
    ('procure wood')
  , ('grab hammer')
  , ('hammer')
  , ('get screw')
  , ('charge drill')
  , ('start drilling')
;

INSERT INTO job_action (JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME)
VALUES
    ('build','procure wood')
  , ('build','grab hammer')
  , ('build','hammer')
  , ('drill','get screw')
  , ('drill','charge drill')
  , ('drill','start drilling')
;

INSERT INTO job_step (JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME, STEP_NO)
VALUES
    ('build','procure wood', 1000000)
  , ('build','grab hammer' , 2000000)
  , ('build','hammer'      , 3000000)

  , ('drill','get screw'     , 1000000)
  , ('drill','charge drill'  , 2000000)
  , ('drill','start drilling', 3000000)
;
```

The query returns correct results

```sql
SELECT JOB_NAME
     , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY JOB_NAME ORDER BY STEP_NO ASC) AS STEP
     , ACTION_NAME
FROM job_step
ORDER BY JOB_NAME ;
```

```
+----------+------+----------------+
| job_name | step | action_name    |
+----------+------+----------------+
| build    | 1    | procure wood   |
| build    | 2    | grab hammer    |
| build    | 3    | hammer         |
| drill    | 1    | get screw      |
| drill    | 2    | charge drill   |
| drill    | 3    | start drilling |
+----------+------+----------------+
```

And to insert the `get nails` to the build job.

```sql
-- first define the new action
INSERT INTO action_ (ACTION_NAME) VALUES ('get nails');

-- associate it with the build job
INSERT INTO job_action (JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME)
VALUES ('build','get nails');

-- insert between grab hammer and hammer
INSERT INTO job_step (JOB_NAME, ACTION_NAME, STEP_NO)
VALUES ('build','get nails', 2500000) ;
```

And now the query returns:

```
+----------+------+----------------+
| job_name | step | action_name    |
+----------+------+----------------+
| build    | 1    | procure wood   |
| build    | 2    | grab hammer    |
| build    | 3    | get nails      |
| build    | 4    | hammer         |
| drill    | 1    | get screw      |
| drill    | 2    | charge drill   |
| drill    | 3    | start drilling |
+----------+------+----------------+
```